# Why is WMV playback cut off (half black)?

Tags: windows-update, wmv, video-playback

Starting today, WMV playback on several software programs is incorrect. The bottom half of the WMV appears correctly, but the top half is black. This happens whether the WMV is scaled or not, and whether it is stretched or not.

The only thing different is Windows Updates were applied yesterday (9 Jul 2013).

**Edit:**

Playback using Windows Media Player seems unaffected. The bug occurs in the aforementioned software as well as, in my experience, [Datastead TVideoGrabber](http://www.datastead.com/products/tvideograbber/overview.html) 8.5.2.2.

Comment: Did your graphics drivers get updated in the process?

Comment: @Karan No, video drivers were not updated. I already discovered the solution (for our software), I wanted to post here for others.

Comment: Ah, good job identifying the source of the problem. I don't use WMVs or WMP so it didn't affect me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uninstalling Windows Update [KB2803821](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2803821) fixes the issue.

This update addresses a security vulnerability in WMV playback, but it appears in software such as [Camtasia Studio](http://feedback.techsmith.com/techsmith/topics/problem_displaying_wmv_object_in_camtasia), [MoviePlusX6](http://forums.serif.com/showthread.php?s=993c04d2b17331a4371109b57fd303a5&p=960763#post960763), and possibly others, this update is causing the half-black playback issue.

Comment: Do WMVs play back correctly in WMP at least? One would suppose MS has checked for compatibility with their own player before releasing the update. Also, hopefully these programs will be updated soon, since a security vulnerability shouldn't remain unpatched for long.

Comment: @Karan Yes actually, they did appear to play back correctly in Windows Media Player (version 12.0.7601.17514 on Windows XP Professional 32-bit).

Comment: Vote for this bug to be fixed on MS Connect: [Windows Media Video 9 decoder (WMV3) incorrectly decodes video into 32-bit RGB format](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794627/windows-media-video-9-decoder-wmv3-incorrectly-decodes-video-into-32-bit-rgb-format)

Answer (score 0):

The flaw seems to be limited to decoding WMVs in directshow and using a sample grabber to readback the frames.  The data received by the sample grabber in the graph is simply half blank and nothing else sticks out (media types, size and flags are all correct).  My software can be configured to use the vmr9 filter with an allocator presenter to grab frames and that technique still works perfectly fine with the update.

Answer (score 0):

it appears to work fine when configuring the samplegrabber by passing a AM_MEDIA_TYPE with subtype = MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24 to ISampleGrabber.[SetMediaType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd376993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

a temporary workaround is to uninstall KB2834902   KB2834903    KB2834904   KB2834905  KB2845142   KB2803821 (depending on the windows media player version)